# Access attributes of a matplotlib plot made through pandas plot function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Say I have a pandas dataframe and I plot it with matplotlib via the pandas built-in function `plot`:

```
mydata = list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
barchart = dataframe.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

How do I access the color of the bars?

More generally, how do I access all the attributes?

E.g. I can get the background color with `barchart.get_axis_bgcolor()` and I can set it to grey with `barchart.set_axis_bgcolor('grey')`, but what about all the other attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of a series you can do this with colors,

```
mydata = list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(mydata) 
barchart = dataframe.plot(kind = 'bar',color=['maroon','purple'])
```

However, with the barchart variable you have a handle on the axes, now you can use get_children() to get a hold of any patches, text, axis, or any other object in the chart to modify just about anything you want.

Comment: Then I guess I do not know how to access the attribute color for the bars. I tried `dir` but found nothing related.

Comment: Also, say I want to change the colors of the bars via a colormap. Using `plot` I'd do something like `plot(..., color=cmap)`. Is it possible to achieve the same through the handles?

Comment: Ok I managed to change colors, e.g.: `barchart.patches[0].set_color('g')`. Great, thank you. What about using a colormap?

Comment: Ok I guess I managed to do that too: just looping over all patches. Great. Thank you for your input. Case dismissed.